# Data and directives (structure)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following your about large Angularjs app structure I'm using this styleguide:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

I developed an **itemManager** (item-manager controller) which has two nested directives (**search-options** and **search-results**).

- Item Manager

  - Search Options (not important for now)
  - Search Result

The item manager template will show the search options and the search results (using an iterator).

The search-result directive controller has all the info needed to show an item.

My problem is that I don't exactly know where to store the information of the array of items I'll show.

The search options will trigger an AJAX call to a REST service that will return a JSON containing the info of all the search results I want to show.
The problem is that I don't know where I should store the array containing the items info.

I think that the markup on the item manager should be something like:

```
<search-result ng-repeat="//iterator"><search-result>
```

but in the Item Manager I don't have access to the search-result variables (they are within the search-result directive scope).

Then, if I store the variable inside the search-result directive I should iterate inside the directive template, which I don't think is right.
Anyone can give me advice on how this should be structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One neat solution would be to store the search results in a service and not rely on prototypical inheritance between scopes. Have a look at this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="itemController">
        <search-options></search-options>
        <search-result ng-repeat="item in items" item="item"></search-result>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.service('searchResultsService', function() {
    var myData = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    return {
        get: function() {
            return myData;
        },
        set: function(data) {myData = data;}
    };
}).controller('itemController', function($scope, searchResultsService) {
    $scope.searchResultsService = searchResultsService;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.$watch('searchResultsService.get()', function(newVal) {
        $scope.items = newVal;
    });
}).directive('searchResult', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p>{{item}}</p>'
    };
}).directive('searchOptions', function(searchResultsService) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-click="search()">Search</button>',
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.search = function() {
                searchResultsService.set(['d', 'e', 'f']);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/x551pmz8/3/

Comment: Thanks! 
Adding the item: '=' to the scope definition is what I needed I think ;)

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept if you like the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You can safely store the data in **itemManager** controller and the directives inside in it will still be able to access it as directives have the scope extended with their parent controller

Comment: Then I should acces via scope.$parent inside the result-item directive?

Comment: You can still access it directly $scope.whateverKey you have used inside the controller

Comment: If you see the styleguide I linked you'll see I'm using controller as syntax, so I don't use $scope.

Comment: sorry my bad scope.whateverKey you can use it directly

Comment: Still, inside the directive if I print the scope I don't see the search results.

Comment: Dont print the scope .. print $scope.whateverKey in the directive as this key is present inside the prototypical inheritance of that scope